# Collect the amount of clicks on a link to Sharepoint, placed in email

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, click

I need to collect the amount of clicks on a link, placed in email.

The idea is following:

1) I send an email message with 1 hyperlink to N people

2) Some of them open it and click this link.

3) Link directs to the file Sharepoint (this is required) page (Library or List) where the below code is placed:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var Loginname = document.getElementById("zz15_Menu");
    var strTrans=Loginname.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
    .... WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?....       
    window.location = "http://www.smth.com/ololo.pdf";
</script>
```

I have user's Display Name in `strTrans` now.

Please suggest something to code next to store this parameter of every page visit in some file, allowing me then to get the amount of link clicks.

I cannot use any server-side technology on Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

The including of a javascript file is enough for Google and others to gather statistics, so why not use some tool like Google Analytics.

If you want to depend on javacript, you could use [jQuery to open an url](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) on the background and gather statistics in there.

Use something like this:

```
$.get('http://url/registerOpen.aspx?username=' + strTrans);
```

Comment: hmm.. will jquery collect every page access by incrementing some counter placed somewhere? I did not understand how your answer will help to resolve the current problem. Can you please explain more detailed, please?

Comment: You need some external tool to register page opens. At Google, your own server, or somewhere else. You can call this by the javascript I provided.

Comment: I have development server with and I can place an ASP page to receive pushed by jQuery data.. will it be a solution?

Comment: It is a certainly a possibility. Just create an ASPX page which writes your desired info to a database. Of course you had better use a production machine...

Comment: Any luck so far? Do you need more help?

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside the paid services (Omniture, WebMetrics, etc.), did you consider Google Analytics?

http://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: That's not an option for my current situation as it's super-secured intranet.

Comment: If you're in an enterprise environment, perhaps they have an internal metrics collection tool that you can use?

Comment: yes, of course, but we need personalized accesses count and strTrans contains exactly username for that purpose.

Comment: Hmm.. do you have access to the server where the pages are located? It's not too hard to write a script that logs some basic timestamp, click, and other useful header information in a .csv file.